# What is the next number?

Tags: pattern

This is an easy number puzzle:

1) 1
2) 11
3) 21
4) 1211
5) 111221
6) 312211
7) 13112221
8) ???

What is the number on row 8?

Comment: Didn't see it's been already posted, sorry guys

Comment: Eh, this one was a little hard to find its dupe, so no biggie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It is:

```
1113213211
```

#### Explanation:

Each number, from the second line onwards, represents the frequencies of the digits in the previous line in the form $Af_ABf_BCf_C...$, where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the different digits in order of appearence, and $f_{A,B,C}$ represents their frequency in every continuous set of equal digits.

```
1
11      one one
21      two ones
1211    one two and one one
111221  one one, one two, and two ones
...
```

Comment: Correct guess but careless answer~

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer adding a more precise explaination